# Unable to retrieve image data from table and display image

Tags: php, mysql, image, mysqli

I'm trying to upload an image file to my database with PHP and MySQLi, but I'm coming across a very confusing piece of error. The table has two column, 'title' and 'image'. The 'title' is for the file's name and 'image' for the image data. both tables are NOT allowed to accept NULLs. When I upload a file, data is stored into the table columns. 'title' contains the right values, but the 'image' column contains '`<binary data>`'.

Since the table column does not accept NULL values I assumed that it is the file's data, but when I try to retrieve and display the image data in showimage.php it tells me the image data is NULL.

I am using the BLOB datatype to store the image data in the table. As far as I am concerned based off the online resources and examples it should work. Thanks.

Code:

PHP:

uploads.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $title = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $data = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $content = file_get_contents($data);
    $query = "INSERT INTO images (title, image) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('sb', $title, $content);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    $creationWasSuccessful = $statement->affected_rows == 1 ? true : false;
    if ($creationWasSuccessful)
    {
        echo "Works!";
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

showimage.php

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = ?";
    $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('i', $id);

    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();

    if ($statement->num_rows >= 1)
    {
        $statement->bind_result($imageid, $title, $image)
        while ($statement->fetch()) {
            if ($image == NULL) {
                echo "Image data does not exist!";
            } else {
                header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                echo $image;
            }

        }        
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form action="uploads.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to save the image from output `file_get_contents` to your database. And then you put that to `imagecreatefromstring` and show your image.

Here's the simple example. Maybe this help you out :)

```
$data = file_get_contents("ACL.jpg");
$img = imagecreatefromstring($data);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);
```

## EDIT :

you just need to put this code :

```
$statement->bind_result($imageid, $title, $image)
while ($statement->fetch()) {
    if ($image == NULL) {
        echo "Image data does not exist!";
    } else {
        $img = imagecreatefromstring($image);
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        imagejpeg($img);
    }

}
```

## EDIT FIX :

`uploads.php`

In this file you need to change your `$statement->bind_param('sb', $title, $content);` become `$statement->bind_param('ss', $title, $content);`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $title = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $data = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $content = file_get_contents($data);
    $query = "INSERT INTO images (title, image) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('ss', $title, $content);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    $creationWasSuccessful = $statement->affected_rows == 1 ? true : false;
    if ($creationWasSuccessful)
    {
        echo "Works!";
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

`showimage.php`
and then in you show it using this :

`$img = imagecreatefromstring($image);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);` in your last statement

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT id,title,image FROM images WHERE id = ?";
    $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('i', $id);

    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();

    if ($statement->num_rows >= 1)
    {
        $statement->bind_result($imageid, $title, $image)
        while ($statement->fetch()) {
            if ($image == NULL) {
                echo "Image data does not exist!";
            } else {
                $img = imagecreatefromstring($image);
                header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                imagejpeg($img);
            }

        }        
    }
}
```

Hope this work fine too, I've tested it and it run well... :)

Comment: you can test it using the first code `$data = file_get_contents("ACL.jpg");
$img = imagecreatefromstring($data);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);` you can tested it too... :)

Comment: I've done all of that. There is no statement error provided. The error that pops up is the "Image data does not exist!" when the image data from the table comes up as NULL. When I upload it, it is apparent that binary data is being placed in the table but comes up as null when being retrieved

Comment: @The_Perfect_Username : I've edited my answer, and I've tested it too, hope it run well, Please tell me if it still error... :)