# Why is the Codeigniter read file not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i am trying to show an image in a controller. it is now showing the image. this is what i tried to do.
1- Hardcode relative image path so that no confusion about the image
2- i put the piece of code in the constructor and it is working before "`parent::__construct();`" line. but it is not showing after this line.

```
class Fileupload extends Frontend_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        //code is working here and showing image

        parent::__construct();

        //code below this line is not working

        $this->load->model('front_end/user_model');
        $dst_path = "C:\\xampp\htdocs\myweb\assets/uploads/avatar.jpg";
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dst_path));
        readfile($dst_path,true);
        die;
    }
```

any suggestion??

Answer (score 1):

Write your code  like this

```
<?php 
class Fileupload extends Frontend_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
   }


 public function index() {
      $this->load->model('front_end/user_model');

      $dst_path   =   "C:\\xampp\htdocs\myweb\assets/uploads/avatar.jpg";

      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

      header('Content-Length: '  .  filesize($dst_path));

      readfile($dst_path,true);

   } 
}
```

?>
The index function is always called by default in any MVC framework. This should help. Do try and tell

Comment: yes i was writing this but it was not working. then i paste in constructor for testing. the result is the same. working before parent::__construct(); but not after that

Comment: You should read some documentation before you really start working on this. And luckily you can find many free sources to work on codeigniter. The code before construct does all..like you want to load a language file or model, etc. but not after it. it is good to load your model, helper files, here. But always place your code in some separate function or the index one.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
function __construct()
{
    //code is working here and showing image

    parent::__construct();

    //code below this line is not working

    $this->load->model('front_end/user_model');

    $dst_path = "C:/xampp/htdocs/myweb/assets/uploads/avatar.jpg";
    $data = file_get_contents($dst_path);
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($img);
    // die;
}
```

Or, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873722/unable-to-retrieve-image-data-from-table-and-display-image) for more examples. :)

Answer (score 0):

it look like you have some output in constructor. that is disturbing the code some space or something else. remove that space from constructor "Frontend_Controller" or use `ob_clean();` before your code so that it

```
class Fileupload extends Frontend_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        ob_clean();// that will clean your browser.

        $this->load->model('front_end/user_model');
        $dst_path = "C:\\xampp\htdocs\myweb\assets/uploads/avatar.jpg";
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dst_path));
        readfile($dst_path,true);
        die;
    }
```